# Vue JS composition API can't access array

Tags: vue.js, vuex, metronic

I am currently trying to learn Vue JS without ever having encountered Javascript.

All the brackets, arrows, etc. are driving me crazy.

With the Composition API, I come across a question that I can't successfully google.

That's working:

```
setup() {
    const store = useStore ();
    const packagingdata = ref ([]);
    const loadpackagingdata = async () => {
      await store.dispatch (Actions.LOADPACKAGING_LIST, 10);
      packagingdata.value = store.getters.getPackagingData;

return {
      packagingdata,
}
```

I can access `{{packagingdata}}`. That contains an array.

`{{Packagingdata.products}}`
does work
but `{{packagingdata.products [0]}}` doesn't work.

But when I add it to the setup () like this:

```
setup() {
        const store = useStore ();
        const packagingdata = ref ([]);
        const getProducts = ref ([]);
        const loadpackagingdata = async () => {
            await store.dispatch (Actions.LOADPACKAGING_LIST, 10);
            packagingdata.value = store.getters.getPackagingData;
            getProducts.value = store.getters.getProducts;      
        };
    return {
        packagingdata,
        getProducts
    }
```

then `{{ getProducts }}` returns what I wanted even if the getter function only is like this:

```
get getAddress() {
    return this.packagingdata["products"][0];
  }
```

What is happening there?
What am I doing wrong? I would prefer to not create a ref() and getterfunction for every computed value.
Whats the solution with computed?

best regards

Comment: In components, we typically create a computed for each getter you want to consume.

Comment: i tried again and probably get the syntax right 
    const productdata = computed(() => {
      return store.getters.getProduct;
    });

but the computed fires before my packagingdata are loaded, although i worked with sync/await on the packagingdata-loadingaction. thats why i get errors for "key not exists in object".

Comment: If you are serious about learning vue.js (or front-end development) I strongly suggest that you should start by learning the fundamentals (html, css and javascript). Believe me, taking your time to learn the basics would immensely help you.

Answer (score 0):

I found two methods to avoid the error.

1. add a v-if="mygetter.length" in the template
2. check in the getter whether the variable is set and otherwise return false

Both of these prevent an error already occurring when the page is loaded that [0] cannot be found